# Python - remove list from lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list from which I would like to delete a list so that I can have the required answer.

```
list = [["hello","son", 52],["welcome","home",65],["good","work",6]]
name = input("Name: ")
if name in list:
    del list[name]
    print("name + " deleted")
else:
    print("invalid name")
```

How can I delete list so that I get this answer:

```
list = [["hello", "son", 52], ["good", "work", 6]]
```

Then add a new list to get this result:

```
list = [["hello", "son", 52], ["good", "work", 6],["see","you","soon"]]
```

Comment: What is `name` supposed to be?

Comment: want name to search the list and delete it in which list it belongs             name = input("Enter name: ") # welcome                                                   
this should search name in list if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate through the list as the key that you are using to evaluate condition is in the sub list.

```
mylist = [["hello","son", 52],["welcome","home",65],["good","work",6]]
name = 'hello' # 'son' would also work
for i, sub_list in enumerate(mylist):
        if name in sub_list:
                del mylist[i]
                print(name + " deleted")
                break

print(mylist)
```

For a given example, where you want to specify bunch of properties for a name; I would have considered using dictionary with name as key.

Comment: if we use name as input variable like                                                       
 name = input("Enter name: ").title()                                                                is it possible to delete a list in lists and get same output as above.                            list is from .csv file

Comment: @Jasd it would still work as long as name is a string object.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to loop through the list of lists using nested while loops!  Check to see if the "name" you asked for is present at the index of the list, and if it is, pop or remove it using the location "[x[y]"(depending on what you want to do with the old/new list.  I am a little unclear based on your phrasing).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the index with what element to use in search. (I assumed index=1 )

```
>>> list = [["hello","son", 52],["welcome","home",65],["good","work",6]]
>>> name="home"
>>> list
[['hello', 'son', 52], ['welcome', 'home', 65], ['good', 'work', 6]]
>>> list = [rec for rec in list if rec[1] != name]
>>> list
[['hello', 'son', 52], ['good', 'work', 6]]
```

Recommended to use Dictionary for this types of data.

Comment: if we use name as input vaiable like   
    
    
    
name = input("Enter name: ").title()



is it possible to delete a list in lists and same output as above

Comment: No data has title form (Ex: Hello). So use name = input("Enter name: ")

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a loop, why not `filter()` with a lambda function? Check it out:

```
>>> l = [["hello","son", 52],["welcome","home",65],["good","work",6]]
>>> name = "home"
>>> filter(lambda sub_list: name not in sub_list, l)
[['hello', 'son', 52], ['good', 'work', 6]]
>>>
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter for more information on `filter()`. Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

Didn't see your last question about adding another list to get the second answer. Try using the `append()` method.

```
>>> l = [["first", "list"]]
>>> m = ["second", "list"]
>>> l.append(m)
>>> l
[['first', 'list'], ['second', 'list']]
>>>
```

Comment: list is from .csv file.

Comment: @Jasd Did you read the data from the .csv file into a list in your script? I'm not sure how that matters.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use list as a variable name , its a type.**

You can simply use a function and use two parameters one for list and another for that word which you want to remove.

```
list_1 = [["hello","son", 52],["welcome","home",65],["good","work",6]]

def deleting(list_1,del_name):
    for sub_list in list_1:
        if del_name in sub_list:
            list_1.remove(sub_list)
    return list_1
print(deleting(list_1,'hello'))
```

output:

```
[['welcome', 'home', 65], ['good', 'work', 6]]
```

As you commented out:

**if we use name as input vaiable like name = input("Enter name: ").title() is it possible to delete a list in lists and same output as above**

Here is the updated solution:

```
list_1 = [["hello","son", 52],["welcome","home",65],["good","work",6]]

def deleting(list_1):
    del_name=input("Enter name: ")
    for sub_list in list_1:
        if del_name in sub_list:
            list_1.remove(sub_list)
    return list_1
print(deleting(list_1))
```

output:

```
Enter name: hello
[['welcome', 'home', 65], ['good', 'work', 6]]
```

Comment: if we use name as input vaiable like   
    
    
    
name = input("Enter name: ").title()



is it possible to delete a list in lists and same output as above

Comment: sure , let me give you one example.

Comment: how about if that list is read from csv file.  Should that list be global or local to def function

Comment: if it is coming from a csv file then just pass to that function which i created above. but keep in mind it should be have same format and nested lists as shown in your dummpy example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove this list of indices from a list of lists, you should try it by for and while loops:

```
Index=[1,4,6,9]
```

list of lists:

```
Coordinates=[[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17],[18,19,20,21],[22,23,24,25],[26,27,28,29],[30,31,32,33],[34,35,36,37],[38,39,40,41]]
```

The output would be:

```
Coordinates=[[2,3,4,5],[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17],[22,23,24,25],[30,31,32,33],[34,35,36,37]]
```

I use this code:
at first sort list of indices:

```
sorted(Index)
while(len(Index)>0):
    del Coordinates[Index[0]]
    del Index[0]
    for i in range(len(Index)):
        Index[i]-=1
print(Coordinates)
```